# Why android application showing application icon instead of my uploaded image?

Tags: android, image, web-services, camera

I have created an android application, where I capture image with camera and upload to server. And I have a image listView where I am showing the images . But the listView is always showing the icon image. I have tested the server image , the image is always uploading but listview is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three method I used to load image is given below.

```
private Drawable ImageOperations(String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sizef=items.size();
        Log.i("Size", sizef+"");
        return items.size();
    }
```

But how to load image now,because the server is now changed from Get method to Post method.
The server using https: